# Exclude Endpoint HTTP methods from Django REST Swagger

Tags: django, swagger

Is there a way to hide just some of the methods of an endpoint and not the whole endpoint? (e.g. show the POST method but hide the DELETE one)

where I have tried to customize the documentation using the `AutoSchema`

For example an endpoint like

```
router.register(r'audittrial', AuditTrialViewSet, 'AuditTrial')
```

would have the following schema defined

```
class AuditTrialCustomView(AutoSchema):

    @staticmethod
    def get_field(name, required, location, schema, description):

        return coreapi.Field(
                    name=name,
                    required=required,
                    location=location,
                    schema=schema,
                    description=description
                )

    def get_manual_fields(self, path, method):

        extra_fields = []

        if method == 'GET':
            extra_fields = [
                self.get_field("from", False, "query", coreschema.String(), "Date of the start of the Audit Trial"),
                ....
            ]
        return extra_fields
```

Is there any method I would be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

DRF has following example - see if it helps you.

```
class CustomAutoSchema(AutoSchema):
    def get_link(self, path, method, base_url):
        # override view introspection here...

@api_view(['GET'])
@schema(CustomAutoSchema())
def view(request):
    return Response({"message": "Hello for today! See you tomorrow!"})
```

so that `api_view` decorator should help you. it takes list of methods in list as an argument.